# Projecting a Point onto a Line

Tags: javascript, math, graph, linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the red point coordinates in this image where the points are projected on to a line formed by the jagged line's start and end point.

[image: Point projection]

I'm using the code from this article, [What are the coordinates of the projected point on a line segment using the perp dot product ?](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/PointOnLine/PointOnLine.html), but it appears that I'm doing something incorrectly. Could someone please help me achieve the result in the above image. Thank you!

```js
const points = [
  { x: 2, y: 2 },
  { x: 3, y: 1 },
  { x: 4, y: 4 },
  { x: 5, y: 3 },
  { x: 6, y: 6 },
  { x: 7, y: 5 },
  { x: 8, y: 6 }
];

const first = points[0];
const last = points.slice(-1)[0];
const d = {
  x: last.x - first.x,
  y: last.y - first.y
};

function dot_product(pt1,pt2)
{
  return pt1.x*pt2.x + pt1.y*pt2.y;
}

function drawChart() { 
  let projected = [];
  for (var i=0; i<points.length; i++)
  {
    p = points[i];
    let e2 = {x:p.x-first.x,y:p.y-first.y};
    let dot = dot_product(d,e2);
    let len2 = d.x * d.x + d.y * d.y;

    let v = {
      x: first.x + (dot*d.x)/ len2,
      y: first.y + (dot*d.y)/ len2,
    }
    projected.push(v);
  }

  chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: false,
    theme: "light2",
    data: [
      {
        type: "line",
        color: "blue",
        lineDashType: "dash",
        indexLabelFontSize: 16,
        dataPoints: [points[0],points.slice(-1)[0]]
      },
      {
        type: "line",
        color: "blue",
        indexLabelFontSize: 16,
        dataPoints: points
      },
      {
        type: "line",
        color: "red",
        indexLabelFontSize: 16,
        dataPoints: projected 
      }
    ]
  });
  chart.render();
}

drawChart();
```

```css
html
{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body
{
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
}

#chartContainer { height: 400px; width: 320px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
```

Comment: nothing wrong with the values. just need to adjust the width/height so that both x and y have same scale

Comment: @cmgchess Thank you! How would I adjust the width/height?

Comment: probably here `#chartContainer { height: 180px; width: 320px; }`

Comment: @cmgchess oh, thank you, but this is for another program (using Python) so unfortunately I can't use CSS.

Comment: there must be  a way to set width and height in python as well. im not sure

Comment: couldnt find a way to set  same scale for x and y in the API itself

Comment: @cmgchess Thank you for checking. Just to see if it fixed it, I made the width & height equal in the CSS. I'm not entirely sure what you mean though.

Comment: Try changing only width keeping height same.

Comment: for example height 400 and width 320 gives somewhat similar scale